# deploy war file in tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat7, apache-axis, axis

I have copied the sample.war file in webapps directory of tomcat.

I can acess localhost:8080.

deploying of wars is automatic by default -i have checked my webapps folder for an extracted folder "sample"

but it is not extracted.why the war file is doesn't extracted.please give me solution for this.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Delete that war file from `webapps/` directory. Then open link `http://localhost:8080/` in your web browser. Click ***Tomcat Manager*** then enter user name and password. In next page you can see one option called ***"WAR file to deploy"***. Select your war file from there and click ***"deploy"*** button.

If you want auto deployment when you copy files to `webapp/` directory. Then make sure that your `server.xml` file contains following values:

```
autoDeploy="true"
unpackWARs="true"
```

Just search these values in your `server.xml` file and edit values as shown above

For more info see [Deploy A New Application from a Local Path](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Deploy_A_New_Application_from_a_Local_Path).

Comment: i have wrote this localhost:8080 means am getting following messages.please refer this:http://screencast.com/t/9h7ytkXRFYz         here Tomcat Manage is not available.

Comment: @user1796222- can you modify your server.xml file as shown above. Also please tell me your result

Comment: this code only saved in my server.xml file.autoDeploy="true" unpackWARs="true".

Comment: i have uploaded one war file yesterday.it is successfully exported and displayed listservices successfully.but today i have upload another war file it is doesn't exported.

Comment: @user1796222- try to login to tomcat. And check your old deployed application is still there. If yes click undeploy. After that try to copy war file into webapps folder

Comment: why i have to undeploy the old one.i have to deploy both war file.

Comment: i got the solution for this.

Comment: @user1796222- i thought you modified you war file and you need to redeploy the app. Thats why i told to undeploy old

Comment: These values are the default. I am facing the same issue I haven't touched those values.. they are true

Answer (score 3):

In general this happens when you have 2 `Tomcats`. If `CATALINA_HOME` is referring to `Tomcat-A` and you are trying to run `Tomcat-B` from `Tomcat-B/bin/startup.bat`. It will run `Tomcat-A`. Hence your war which you are trying to deploy in `Tomcat-B` will not be extracted as `Tomcat-A` is running in actual.